# Maven war plugin: archiveClasses without archiving resources

Tags: java, resources, maven, war

There is an `archiveClasses` option in maven-war-plugin, which packages all the classes in a single .jar, and then creates .war file with that jar in lib/ folder.

I need to do the same, but leave resource files in classes directory, so that they are still accessible from the classpath but easy to modify.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try to configure your resources folder as a WebResource in the 
plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It works, but resources are also duplicated in a jar.

Answer (score 2):

> **One line answer :**  There are no options provided in `maven-war-plugin` to exclude the resources from the jar created using `archiveClasses` flag.

The possible and easiest workaround for this problem is to move the files present under `src/main/java/resources` directory to `src/main/java/webapp/WEB-INF/classes` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to specify where those resources are.  It usually looks in src/main/resources for resources, but if you need them in the java source tree you could try:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>*.xml</include>                
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: No-no. They are exactly in src/main/resources, but I just want them to be packaged into the classes/ directory inside .war file, while the Java .class files should be inside the .jar in lib/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this to solve the problem:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <warName>${project.war.name}</warName>
        <warSourceExcludes>**/*.class</warSourceExcludes>
        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```